# Gradle: Run Integration tests during deployment, not during install

Tags: maven, unit-testing, testing, gradle, integration-testing

I'm looking for both advice on best practices as well as how to implement this.

We have to types of tests, ones that have dependencies mocked out using Mockito (Unit tests, because they're testing on unit of code), and do soup-to-nuts (RESTful Resource -> Database, call them integration tests).

The Integration tests are booting a new JVM and are populating an H2 database, so they take a bit longer to run.

Ideally, we'd want the Unit tests to run when you give the command `gradle test`, but if you were to do a deployment we'd want the integration tests to run as well.

Anyway, I'm curious what people have done to much sure integration tests run before deployment, or if they've solved this another way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use task dependencies to assure integration task is executed before deploy task.

Let's say the task that is running your integration tests is named `integTestTask`, and deployment task named `deployTask`

```
deployTask.dependsOn integTestTask
```

This command make sure when you executed `gradle deployTask` integration task will run before deployment task. Check pages below for seperating unit tests and integration tests.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:task_dependencies

https://www.michael-bull.com/blog/2016/06/04/separating-integration-and-unit-tests-with-gradle